# How can i fix this split in half and become invisible of the div which has a animation of rotateY

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="aDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.container .aDiv {
    height: 25rem;
    width: 25rem;
    background-color: #f12369;
    backface-visibility: visible;
    transition: all 2s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.container .aDiv:hover {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

https://codepen.io/Menax47/pen/WNyvWYo

on hover on the div you will get a rotateY animation.. but the problem is it split the div in half if i use background color to the parent div....how can i solve this problem...

https://codepen.io/Menax47/pen/WNyvWYo

div will rotate without spliting div in half and dissapare

Comment: comments in css are written like so : `/* comments */`  not `//` , thats why parts of your css is not applied on codepen 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The black background of the wrapper bothers you. Make the background of the wrapper transparent and it will work.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.container .aDiv {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vh;
  background-color: #f12369;
  backface-visibility: visible;
  transition: all 2s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.container .aDiv:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="aDiv"></div>
</div>
```